# In a unital division algebra, does the unit have norm 1?

Tags: abstract-algebra, normed-spaces, homotopy-theory, division-algebras

Suppose that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a unital division algebra.
That is, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is furnished with a bilinear map
$$ *: \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n $$
such that
$$ x*y = 0 \implies x=0 \text{ or }y=0. $$
In addition, there is a distinguished element $\mathbf{1}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ where
$$ \mathbf{1}*x = x*\mathbf{1} = x $$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Is it now true that $$ \| \mathbf{1} \| =1 $$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is the usual euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$? In other words, is the unit of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$?

I have tried proving that
$$ \|x*y\| =\|x\|\|y\| \quad \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n $$
without success. Of course, if this above equation holds, then $\|\mathbf{1}\|=1$ is an immediate consequence.

A positive answer to this question would help me prove the following assertion: If $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a unitial division algebra, then the sphere $S^{n-1}$ is an $H$-space.

Of course, I cannot use the classification of division algebras over $\mathbb{R}$, to just say "well in all four cases, $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}, \mathbb{H}, \mathbb{O}$ the unit clearly has norm $1$."

**EDIT:** Apparently the result $\|\mathbf{1}\|=1$ is false, which puts me back at square one.

Comment: If you are willing to say farewell to associativity and a few other things you hold dear, then in fact there are examples of real division algebras that do not satisy $\|x*y\| = \|x\|*\|y\|$. The one that do are called normed division algebras and to them the classification you mention applies. It is also true that *any* real division algebra must have dimension 1, 2, 4 or 8 but that is a much harder result.

Answer (score 1):

> A positive answer to this question would help me prove the following assertion: If $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a unitial division algebra, then the sphere $S^{n-1}$ is an $H$-space.

You don't need the fact you're trying to prove to prove this. $S^{n-1}$ can be defined without any reference to the Euclidean norm, as the quotient of $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$ by scalar multiplication by positive reals (very similar to the construction of real projective space). The multiplication on an $n$-dimensional unital division algebra induces a multiplication on this quotient because, by hypothesis, the product of two nonzero elements is nonzero, and the multiplication is bilinear so respects scalars. And the image of $1$ under this quotient map continues to act as an identity.

Said more concretely, instead of using the multiplication $\ast$ you started with, you can consider "normalized multiplication" $\frac{x \ast y}{\| x \ast y \|}$, which by construction has the property that if $\| x \| = 1$ and $\| y \| = 1$ then $ \| x \ast y \| = 1$, and also that $1$ continues to act as an identity (on the unit sphere).

The recognition that we can scale multiplication arbitrarily (in a way that depends on the vector, even) shows that the fact you're trying to prove can't possibly be true, since e.g. we can consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the scaled multiplication $x \ast y = 2xy$, which has an identity given by $\frac{1}{2}$ which does not have Euclidean norm $1$.

Comment: So the answer is "no the unit of the division algebra does not necessarily have norm 1"? Without this result, I have no idea how to prove that the induced multiplication maps are homotopic to the identity, which is what is required to show $S^{n-1}$ is an $H$-space.

Comment: @Caleb: both of the constructions I described have the property that an identity for the original multiplication continues to be an identity for the multiplication on $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: how can that be true if the unit of the division algebra is not guaranteed to be contained in $S^{n-1}$? the induced multiplication is a map $S^{n-1}\times S^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}$.

Comment: @Caleb: please reread the constructions again. They both construct a map $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ 0 \} \to S^{n-1}$, so every nonzero vector defines a point in $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: I see that, but how can you say $\mathbf{1}$ doesn't have norm $=1$, and then write $\mathbf{1}\in S^{n-1}$ ?

Comment: @Caleb: this is an abuse of notation. Strictly speaking I've defined a map $f : \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ 0 \} \to S^{n-1}$ and I'm talking about $f(1)$. I'll edit it to be a little clearer.